# SVG blur very choppy in firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, svg-filters

I am using svg blur filter on an image, like the following

```
<svg id="blurjs-10">
   <filter id="blur10px">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" in="SourceGraphic">
   </filter>
</svg>
```

But firefox's visual output with this blur is really bad.

[image: svg blur comparison in browsers]

Any solutions guys?

Comment: You say "performance" but you seem to be complaining about the visual quality. Are you actually talking about the rendering speed, or just the appearance?

Comment: @TedMielczarek sorry about the confusion, i meant only the appearance ... performance is actually better since it is not proper blur

Comment: In what way is it not a proper blur? How many UAs have you compared to establish that Firefox is the odd one out?

Comment: @RobertLongson I have tried this in Google Chrome, IE, Safari (including in ipad) if that is what you meant

Comment: This is only on windows, firefox on Mac is just fine

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue too. The problem seems to be that color filter calculations are done with inadequate precision, which leads to color banding.

The solution that seems to fix the issue (at least on my case) is to use [color-interpolation-filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color-interpolation-filters) to ensure the calculations are performed on a wider color space. for example:

```
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
```

After learning about this attribute, the problem and its solution make a lot more sense.